# Dynamically allocating an array of a struct

Tags: c, malloc

I am having a hard time dealing with malloc in  C especially when allocating for array of struct. I have a program that basically store all the filenames and filesize in an array of struct. I got my program working without using malloc but I dont really like this way of programming.  Could I get any help using malloc, in my program?

```
int getNumberOfFiles(char *path)
{
 int totalfiles = 0;
 DIR *d;
 struct dirent *dir;
 struct stat cstat;
 d = opendir(path);
 while(( dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
     totalfiles++;
}
return totalfiles;
}

int main()
{

      int totalfiles = getNumberOfFiles(".");
      int i =0;
      DIR *d;
      struct dirent *dir; 
      d = opendir(".");
      struct fileStruct fileobjarray[totalfiles];
      struct stat mystat;

       while(( dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        fileobjarray[i].filesize=mystat.st_size;
        strcpy (fileobjarray[i].filename ,dir->d_name );
        i++;
      }

}
```

As you can see, I made a function called getnumberoffiles() to get the size to allocate statically.

Comment: instead of showing us what works with a VLA, show us what doesn't work when you try to use `malloc`.

Comment: For creating arrays you might find `calloc` more intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct fileStruct fileobjarray[totalfiles];
```

fileobjarray is a [VLA](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) array of size totalfiles of fileStruct structure. To allocate using [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) we can write:

```
struct fileStruct *fileobjarray = malloc(totalfiles * sizeof(*fileobjarray));
```

We would allocate memory for an array of `totalfiles` elements, with each element of `sizeof(*fileobjarray) = sizeof(struct fileStruct)` size. Sometimes [calloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) is more preferable call in C, as it protects (on some platforms) against overflow:

```
struct fileStruct *fileobjarray = calloc(totalfiles, sizeof(*fileobjarray));
```

And remember to `free()`.

```
int getNumberOfFiles(char *path)
{
 int totalfiles = 0;
 DIR *d;
 struct dirent *dir;
 struct stat cstat;
 d = opendir(path);
 while(( dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
     totalfiles++;
}
return totalfiles;
}

int main()
{

      int totalfiles = getNumberOfFiles(".");
      int i =0;
      DIR *d;
      struct dirent *dir; 
      d = opendir(".");
      struct fileStruct *fileobjarray = calloc(totalfiles, sizeof(*fileobjarray));
      if (fileobjarray == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory!\n");
            return -1;
      }
      struct stat mystat;

      while(( dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        fileobjarray[i].filesize=mystat.st_size;
        strcpy (fileobjarray[i].filename ,dir->d_name );
        i++;
      }
      free(fileobjarray);
}
```